# Caffe - How to make Python API generate runtime input prototxt

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I need the python API to generate such a prototxt :

```
input: "data"
input_dim: 7
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 368
input_dim: 368
input: "heatmap"
input_dim: 7
input_dim: 15
input_dim: 46
input_dim: 46
input: "center_map"
input_dim: 7
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 368
input_dim: 368
input: "h_t_1"
input_dim: 7
input_dim: 48
input_dim: 46
input_dim: 46
input: "cell_t_1"
input_dim: 7
input_dim: 48
input_dim: 46
input_dim: 46
```

How does one go about doing this? I tried doing this:

```
        caffeNet.tops['x'] = L.Data(name="x")
        caffeNet.tops['y'] = L.Data(name="y")
        caffeNet.tops['z'] = L.Data(name="z")
```

But this only generates in this format which is invalid syntax:

```
layer {
  name: "h_t"
  type: "Data"
  top: "h_t"
}
layer {
  name: "cell_t"
  type: "Data"
  top: "cell_t"
}
layer {
  name: "last_paf"
  type: "Data"
  top: "last_paf"
}
```

If I try to load my net with this format, it crashes, it only seems to accept the other format. I could write a hacky script to convert it but surely there is a better way

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`"Input"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/input.html) layers:

```
caffeNet.tops['data'] = L.Input(name="data", 
                                input_param={"shape":{"dim":[7, 3, 368, 368]}})
caffeNet.tops['heatmap'] = L.Input(name="heatmap", 
                                input_param={"shape":{"dim":[7, 15, 46, 46]}})
caffeNet.tops['center_map'] = L.Input(name="center_map", 
                                input_param={"shape":{"dim":[7, 1, 368, 368]}})
```

and so on.